# How to get AWS RDS IP range

Tags: amazon-rds

I see AWS has IP ranges in JSON format. It’s really difficult to find very specific. My question regarding,

How to find RDS IP address range for a particular region?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IP address range for RDS is not officially provided. Your best bet is to filter the list down to `AMAZON` service with IPv4. Since RDS is probably run on EC2, if you want to be risky, you can use `EC2` filter.

Comment: I think, this is Sad part. If we can’t find IP address range then , how to set EC2 outbound rules so that it can connect to RDS instance?

Comment: Oh, if you connect RDS inside VPC, then you don't need the public IP of RDS. Use security group instead to restrict the traffic. @AskMe